# Spring Jackson conditional root wrapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a domain object that for one request only I need to wrap the root with "row" (for DataTables Editor).

The problem is that I only want the root wrapped in the response body of one controller method.

Any suggestions how to conditionally enable root wrapping in one controller method only?  I thought about enabling it in the one method and then writing a pointcut around *controller to disable it on subsequent requests, but there's gotta be a better way...

My Spring configuration is:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(jackson2Converter());
}

@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jackson2Converter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper());
    return converter;
}

@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return objectMapper;
}
```

This works except for the case where I want to wrap my POJO using @JsonRootName, e.g.:
    @JsonRootName("row")

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating a new object mapper in the controller and returning the JSON as a String, e.g.:

```
ObjectMapper rootMapper = new ObjectMapper();
rootMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
return rootMapper.writeValueAsString(myObject);
```

This also meant configuring a String message converter:

```
@Bean
public StringHttpMessageConverter stringMessageConverter() {
    StringHttpMessageConverter converter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    return converter;
}
```