# Spring Adding Json Root Name at controller level

Tags: json, spring

Is there a way to add root element at @controller level and not at application level. I need response in below format

```
{"BaseResponse":{"HeaderResponse":{"prop1":"test","prop2":"1"},"DetailResponse":[{"recordDesc":"record1","recordId":1},{"recordDesc":"record1","recordId":1}]}}
```

But I do not get "BaseResponse" at root

```
{"HeaderResponse":{"prop1":"test","prop2":"1"},"DetailResponse":[{"recordDesc":"record1","recordId":1},{"recordDesc":"record1","recordId":1}]}
```

I dont want to configure WRAP_ROOT_VALUE at application level as below.

```
 public class SpringMVCJacksonObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper  
 {
        public SpringMVCJacksonObjectMapper() 
        {
            super();
            this.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
            this.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating conditional ObjectMapper at controller level solved the issue.

[here is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30247251/6030112)